# How to prevent Spinner announcement when initialized

Tags: android, android-spinner, talkback, accessibility

**Background**

The fragment creates it's views and then starts a network operation.  When the network operation is completed, various types of subviews are created and added to the fragment's view, based on the results of the network operation.

**Problem**

If a `Spinner` is added by the fragment, it's initial value is announced by TalkBack.  This is very undesirable because the Spinner is usually buried deep within the form.

**Failed Solutions**

I've tried:

1. wrapping addView with `setImportantForAccessibility`
2. not setting the initial `Spinner` value (not an acceptable solution in any case) but the initial value is still announced when added
3. setting the `Spinner`'s `contentDescription` to non-breaking space before adding and restoring it in `onAttachedToWindow` *

**Question**

`Spinner` is created and dynamically added, after the fragment is initially created.   How can I prevent TalkBack from announcing the initial value of the `Spinner`?

Comment: i suppose you retrieve data to list first and display it into spinner ?

Comment: @IbrahimAli I'm not sure what you're asking.  When the fragment is initially displayed we start a long running operation which will eventually result in a Spinner being created and displayed, along with a lot of other elements.  The list of elements is dynamic, depending on the contents of the network operation.  When the Spinner is finally displayed, we don't want it's value to be announced (or indeed, for anything to be announced)

Comment: i mean why you didn't try to remove initial value from list  while onCreating your spinner `yourList.remove("yourinitial")`.

Comment: The Spinner needs to initially show the correct (current) value.  Whenever I set that initial value it's going to announce it, that announcement is what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: Why would you want to avoid sending helpful information to blind users? Just because it's buried, doesn't mean that it's not important.

Comment: When the view is first created it should announce the activity header and perhaps content towards the top of the screen.  In this case it's announcing content which, at best, is towards the bottom of the screen, and possibly not visible at all.  I'm not asking about not announcing it at all, just not announcing something largely irrelevant when the fragment is first presented.

Comment: @DavidBerry Did you solve it? If yes, can you please post the solution? I am looking for similar solution.

Comment: Still no solution? I am facing the same issue where I am populating my view dynamically and that includes a spinner which is read out as soon as its loaded on screen (even when its not the first item on the list).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a workaround that I did in my project which worked as expected i.e. Spinner's content is only read out by TalkBack when it's in focus.

I subclassed the `AppCompatSpinner` class and overrode its `onInitializeAccessibilityEvent` function as follows:

```
@Override
public void onInitializeAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {
    if (event.getEventType() == AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_ACCESSIBILITY_FOCUSED) {
        super.onInitializeAccessibilityEvent(event);
    }
}
```

Comment: I was able to replace my hack with this solution, but used an `AccessibilityDelegate` instead of subclassing spinner.

Comment: @DavidBerry cool .. can you share that as an answer to this question instead of a comment?

Answer (score 0):

1) set important for accessibility to false to all spinners in your form in onCreate().

```
spinner.setImportantForAccessibility(View.IMPORTANT_FOR_ACCESSIBILITY_NO);
```

2) setOnHoverListener to each spinner and inside it enable the accessibility again and send accessibility events to announce them properly.

```
spinner.setImportantForAccessibility(View.IMPORTANT_FOR_ACCESSIBILITY_YES);
spinner.sendAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_ACCESSIBILITY_FOCUSED);
spinner.sendAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_FOCUSED);
spinner.sendAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_CLICKED);
```

3) setOnTouchListener to each spinner to perform click after double tap.

```
spinner.performClick();
```